# Cannot login to administrator page after upgrading Joomla 1.5.7 to 1.5.25

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

currently i'm using joomla 1.5.7. when i updating it to joomla 1.5.25 using this patch Joomla_1.5.0_to_1.5.25-Stable-Patch_Package.tar.gz. my page look fine but when i want to login to admin page. i cannot login and there is no error message. When I enter wrong password it show an error but when i insert correct password, it will redirect to main login page again

Thanks

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? Do you really want to downgrade from 1.5.7 to 1.5.25 using the package 1.5.0_to_1.5.25 ? Please turn on php's "display_errors" to "On" so that you can show us the error message that will appear, when logggin in.

Comment: Is there not a 1.5.7 -> 1.5.25 patch?

Comment: i'm using update manager and it was automatic update

Comment: I have a similar problem, went from 1.5.14 to 1.5.27 , did you finally resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you receive no error when you enter the right user/password combination, and you are getting errors otherwise, maybe the error is related with the session.
Maybe during the upgrade process the session handler configuration was misconfigured somehow?
Open your configuration.php file (inside the joomla root folder) and look if there's a line like this:

```
var $session_handler = 'database';
```

If it's empty, then your session won't work. You can try to manually change it to 'database' or 'file'.
If this did not solved your problem, then try enabling display errors to see if you're getting some other errors.

I hope it helped!